# clang++ undefined reference to function even though it exists

Tags: android, c++, linker, clang++

I'm trying to create some simple binary to call an exported function from the shared object libQREngine.camera.samsung.so

This is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int Java_com_samsung_android_qrengine_QRBarcodeDecoder_getRecogObjectCount();

int main()
{
int test=  Java_com_samsung_android_qrengine_QRBarcodeDecoder_getRecogObjectCount();
return 0;
}
```

This is how I try to compile and link it:

```
aarch64-linux-android29-clang++ -o test test.cpp -L./lib64 -lQREngine.camera.samsung  -Wl,-rpath ./lib64
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniThrowException@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniThrowNullPointerException@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniGetReferent@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniGetNioBufferBaseArrayOffset@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `JniInvocationCreate@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniThrowIOException@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniLogException@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniGetNioBufferBaseArray@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniGetFDFromFileDescriptor@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `JniInvocationDestroy@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `JniInvocationInit@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniThrowExceptionFmt@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniThrowRuntimeException@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniSetFileDescriptorOfFD@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniCreateFileDescriptor@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniGetNioBufferPointer@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniGetNioBufferFields@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so: undefined reference to `jniRegisterNativeMethods@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1'
```

I do understand libandroid_runtime.so needs to import these functions from "libnativehelper.so".
It's also written as the dependency when looking with readelf -d ./lib64/libandroid_runtime.so

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnativehelper.so]
```

nm -D ./lib64/libnativehelper.so also shows these functions exist as in:

```
00000000000034f0 T jniThrowExceptionFmt
0000000000003570 T jniThrowNullPointerException
0000000000003f58 T jniGetReferent
0000000000003d18 T jniGetNioBufferBaseArrayOffset
00000000000050e8 T JniInvocationCreate
0000000000003590 T jniThrowIOException
0000000000003608 T jniLogException
0000000000003c30 T jniGetNioBufferBaseArray
```

And so on, I left some out on purpose not to make this post larger.
Strace also shows libnativehelper.so is being opened and closed at some point before the error happens.

Now I don't understand why the linker wouldn't use these functions even though they exist inside libnativehelper.so and that file is inside ./lib64/

Edit: It seems like this has something to do with the symbol versioning of libnativehelper.so. As you can see above the function "jniThrowException" and "jniThrowException@LIBNATIVEHELPER_1" are quiet different which is probably the reason the linker doesnt want to link them.

Comment: https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1186, you're probably not supposed to link to `libQREngine.camera.samsung.so` in ndk applications

Comment: "If you need those libraries, you need to copy them into your APK."
It should be possible to link them and even if not I would like to know why it's not possible.

My idea to create the binary is based on this fuzzer: https://github.com/googleprojectzero/SkCodecFuzzer

There he links against libhwui.so which just the as libQREngine.camera.samsung.so resides inside /system/lib64/.

I'm not trying to create an NDK application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the symbol versioning which resulted in having 2 functions, one expected the "LIBNATIVEHELPER_1" version while the libnativehelper.so couldn't provide that version even though it had these functions.

All I had to do was to compile libnativehelper.so through Googles AOSP build system (make sure you compile it in arm64) and take the one which had that version (by grepping)